# How to return List<Map<String, Object>> using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-native-query

I want to return a List of maps from my `createNativeQuery().getResultList()`, where each map is a pair key - value representing column name - value. I already tried to use direct in the method like this:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> execQuery(String nativeQuery) {
    return entityManager().query(nativeQuery).getResultList();
}
```

but it always return List. Someone knows if what I want is even possible?
The JPA implementation that I'm using is Hibernate. I'm currently using Java 8 (don't know if this information is relevant for my case).
Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: does sth like this work for you? `Query q1 = entityManager().query(nativeQuery); org.hibernate.Query hibernateQuery =((org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateQuery)q1)
.getHibernateQuery();
hibernateQuery.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);`

Comment: You can't with a query alone in JPQL. Convert the results yourself into what you need

Comment: @Apostolos Thank you very much, this solved my problem :D. This will tie my application to Hibernate but it's not a problem right now :).

Comment: let me post it as an answer to accept it :)

Comment: @BillyFrost Yep I was doing the conversion by myself until I saw the Apostolos 's answer. I don't mind to tie my application to a JPA implementation (hibernate in this case).

Comment: sometimes i also try not to do jpa-implementation-library-specific stuff but what are the chances of changing library? so instead of struggling to find a JPA-generic solution, in some parts of code i prefer using hibernate-specific parts too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with

```
Query q1 = entityManager().query(nativeQuery); 
org.hibernate.Query hibernateQuery =((org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateQuery)q1) .getHibernateQuery(); 
hibernateQuery.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);‌​
```

Answer (score 2):

You can to use the ResultTransformer to transform your results in a map form.
[Following the oficial documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/RootEntityResultTransformer.html)

Like this:

```html
List<Map<String,Object>> mapaEntity = session
    .createQuery( "select e  from Entity" )
    .setResultTransformer(new AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer())
    .list();
```

Comment: This seems to be a cleaner solution, but in my current application I don't have access to the `org.hibernate.Session` :(, but thanks for you answer :)